# Configure Docker containers to communicate through network

Tags: docker, docker-network

How can a docker container be configured to communicate with another docker container through network?
In my case, redis is running in a docker container with port 6379 opened. It can be access from host machine. I have started another container that needs to access redis, but it is not available.
Setting network_mode to host didn't fix solve the problem.

Answer (score 0):

I usually connect conainters using [network](https://docs.docker.com/network/). In my project, I have two containers one as an dotnet core application and another a database and I'll connect these two using the following docker-compose file:

```
services:       
    coreapi:
      ports: 
        - "8088:80"
      volumes:
        - ~/logs/dockerlogs/coreapi:/app/logs        
      networks: 
        - test

    mongodb:
      ports: 
        - "27017:27017"
        - "27018:27018"
        - "27019:27019"
      networks: 
        - test

networks: 
     test:
         external: true
```

Comment: yeah, this is a solution, but I can access then using docker container name http://my-service.. I would prefer to access using localhost. Some services are running on local machine.